# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scripts')

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, node-modules, laravel-mix

I use node v20.9.0, npm v10.1.0

When I running npm run watch throws the following error:

> [webpack-cli] TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'scripts')
> at Object. (c:\OSPanel\domains\dispatcher\webpack.mix.js:16:4)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
> at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
> at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
> at module.exports (c:\OSPanel\domains\dispatcher\node_modules\laravel-  mix\setup\webpack.config.js:11:5)
> at loadConfigByPath (c:\OSPanel\domains\dispatcher\node_modules\webpack-cli\lib\webpack-cli.js:1445:37)
> at async Promise.all (index 0)

My package.json

```
"scripts": {    
    "dev": "npm run development",  
    "development": "mix",
    "watch": "mix watch",  
    "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",  
    "hot": "mix watch --hot",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "mix --production"
},
"devDependencies":  
    "axios": "^1.6.1",    
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",      
    "cross-env": "^5.0.1",      
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",  
    "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49",  
    "lodash": "^4.17.4",  
    "vue": "^2.1.10",  
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",  
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"  
}
```

My webpack.mix.js

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css').
mix.scripts([
    'public/test/jquery.easing.1.3.js',
    'public/test/retina-1.1.0.min.js',
    'public/test/jquery.cookie.js',
    'public/test/styleswitch.js',
    'public/test/jquery.smartmenus.min.js',
    'public/test/jquery.smartmenus.bootstrap.min.js',
    'public/test/owl.carousel.min.js',
    'public/test/jflickrfeed.js',
    'public/test/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js',
    'public/test/jquery.isotope.min.js',
    'public/test/swipe.js',
    'public/test/jquery.sticky.js',
    'public/test/main.js',  
],  
    'public/js/all.js').mix.scripts([
    'public/test/fileinput.min.js',
    'public/test/inputmask.js',
    'public/test/jquery.inputmask.js',
    'public/test/flash_message.js',
    'public/test/select2.min.js',
    'public/test/ru.js',
    'public/test/text_area_counter.js',
    'public/test/text_area_counter.js',
    'public/test/file_input.js',
 ], 'public/js/libs.js');
```

How can I fix this error?

I try reinstalling webpack-cli and clearing the npm cache (npm cache clean --force) but it did not help

Comment: Please provide the "webpack.mix.js" file content. And what is the "mix watch"? What binary is it (mix?)

Comment: @TalRofe "npm run watch" turn on watch mode and run Mix tasks . This means that after the initial build, webpack will continue to watch for changes in any of the resolved files

Comment: using ׳.sass('...').mix׳ does not seem valid. Maybe try to explain what are you trying to do?

Comment: @TalRofe I'm trying to compile JS scripts to run my project. It's legacy code so I can't explain some used solutions. While I'm running the server locally, I only see a white screen. Everything works correctly in production, but not locally

Comment: I used your same code and it alerts on an error because doing "sass(...).mix(..)" is not valid. The object return by sass(...) does not contain a method called "mix". What version is "laravel-mix" on production?

Comment: @TalRofe laravel-mix v1.4.2

Comment: This is very very low version.. "1" versus "6". A lot of major versions between, of course the code you expect to work won't work with version "6". Is it possible to upgrade the production's dependency version?

Comment: @TalRofe I will try

Comment: I would also reckon on checking your code before using this: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBCYAPOAzKERwOQBsCGU+AbgKa4C0iS2A3AFBA
You can enter any code you want (like the one you provided here in the question) and check whether it works.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem were node-sass and node-gyp. Reinstalling node-gyp and downgrading laravel-mix to v1 and node to v16.20.2 solved it